# How do I put whats in a textbox inside of quotes?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a program that will ping an IP that is entered into a textbox.

If I try calling on the textbox, it will just use the textbox's name as text and put it inside of the command line which will cause the command line to screw up.

How do I make it so it inserts what I enter in the textbox, into the command line?

My Code So Far:

```
  Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    Process.Start("CMD", "/C ping >IP HERE< -t")
End Sub
```

Comment: I know your question wasn't about how to ping, but you may want to check out the [`Ping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming your textbox is named `TextBox1`, you simply get its `.Text` property. So your string would be `"/C ping " & TextBox1.Text)` Read more on it at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19tt6sk(v=vs.110).aspx).

btw, this is VB.Net code. Might want to remove the VBA and VBScript tags.

Answer (score 1):

Check out string.Format(). You can replace wildcards in a string via a parameter array, gives it a bit of a clean look instead of +'s and &'s everywhere.

```
Process.Start("CMD", String.Format("/C ping {0}", Textbox1.Text))
```

Reference for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx